# Any security issues accessing $_POST and returning values from it in AJAX commands?

Tags: forms, ajax, security

Just wondering if there needs to be any sanitization here:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ajax_render_alter().
 */
function my_module_ajax_render_alter(&$commands) {
  if (isset($_POST['_triggering_element_name'])) {
    $commands[] = array(
      'command' => 'myCustomCommand',
      'data' => $_POST['_triggering_element_name'],
    );
  }
}
```